# hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to connect to server error while trying to read data from hdfs from another machine

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am using hdfs in AWS RDP, and trying to access that HDFS from my local machine. While doing that I am being able to list the file using ls command but while trying to read any file I am getting error as - `INFO  security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping: Error getting groups`
White listing of the static IP of the RDP has been done.
The following properties has been set to false - `dfs.permissions,dfs.permissions.superusergroup`

Anyone facing the same or anyone have solution please assist.

Comment: 1) RDP is a just remote desktop. That's not HDFS... Aws EMR / EC2 offers HDFS. 2) The Log level literally says INFO, not ERROR, so is this actually causing a problem? 3) If you're using windows, `UnixGroupsMapping` don't really exist

Comment: 1) We are using the remote desktop and in that, we have installed Hadoop and using hdfs. 2) While trying to access data from that remote desktop's hdfs from my local system I am getting that info as "INFO  security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping: Error getting groups", so yes this seems like is causing an issue.

Comment: Thanks. You don't need to repost the error full your question. I'm simply questioning why you need a desktop environment at all when EMR is right there (and you didn't answer my point about Windows)